# syntax of Ubound(Array) where array is a Union of ranges

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, syntax

I used to have my arrays defined as Array = "Range". Due to problems this caused, I have redefined my arrays as a union of 2 columns. Unfortunately, the syntax Ubound(Array, dimension) now throws an error. If somebody could explain how the syntax works with my new definition, that would be much appreciated.

This is the code for defining the arrays:

```
Sub define_array_5(Array_1)

    Dim wsh As Worksheet

    Dim range1 As Range
    Dim range2 As Range
    Dim finalrange As Range

    Dim a As Integer
    Dim finalrow As Integer

    ' define array

    finalrow = Range("a1").End(xlDown).row

    Set range1 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(finalrow, 1))
    Set range2 = Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(finalrow, 5))
    Set finalrange = Union(range1, range2)

    ReDim Array_1(1 To finalrange.Areas.Count)

    For a = 1 To finalrange.Areas.Count
    Array_1(a) = finalrange.Areas(a)
    Next

End Sub
```

I've figured out that, for instance, what was Array_1(3, 2) in the old definition is now Array_1(2)(3, 1) but the syntax for Ubound is escaping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking doesn't make sense in your example.

You are explicitly defining `Array_1` to be a single dimension array of Areas, each of which has upper bounds.

```
'this dimensions it as a 1-D array
ReDim Array_1(1 To finalrange.Areas.Count)
```

I think what you are looking for is as follows:

```
For a = 1 To finalrange.Areas.Count
    Array_1(a) = finalrange.Areas(a)
    'this is what I think you are trying to do
    Debug.Print UBound(Array_1(a))

Next
```

This gives you the upper bound of the array element `a` of your 1-D array.

Comment: Sorry, I was going to but got distracted with code before the 10 minutes limit passed